# How to npm install custom build angular-ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

On the angular-ui-bootstrap website you can create custom build. Is that possible with npm install?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is a facility with npm install. Go with build tool http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/